# HTML5: Antialiasing leaves traces when I erase the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite, antialiasing

I want to move a widget around on the canvas, and for various reasons I don't want to use sprites. I'm using the latest version of Chrome. In order to move the widget, I 'undraw' it and then redraw it in another place. By 'undraw', I mean that I just draw the same image in the same place, but draw it with the same color as the background, so the widget disappears completely before I draw the new one. The problem is that when I 'undraw', traces of the original image remain on the canvas. I've poked around on related questions here and haven't found anything that helps. I understand the problem of drawing a one-pixel line and getting anti-aliasing, so I set my line width to 2 (and various other non-integer values), but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas? Here's a [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cMVSA/11/), and here's the function that does the update:

```
function draw(){
    if(previousX !== null) {
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
        drawCircle(previousX, previousY, 20);
    }

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    drawCircle(x, y, 20);

        console.log('drew circle (' + x + ', ' + y + ')');

    previousX = x;
    previousY = y;
}
```

P.S. I'm just a hobbyist with no great experience in graphics, so please dumb-down your answer a bit if possible.

Comment: I added the javascript tag for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your draw a shape with anti-aliasing, you are doing a solid covering of some pixels, but only a partial covering of the edge pixels.  The trouble is that pixels (temporarily ignoring LCD panels) are indivisible units.  So how do we partially cover pixels?  We achieve this using the alpha channel.

The alpha channel (and alpha blending) combines the colour at the edge of a circle with the colour underneath it.  This happens when the circle only partially covers the pixel.  Here's a quick diagram to visualise this issue.

[image]

The mixing of colours causes a permanent change that is not undone by drawing the circle again in the background colour.  The reason: colour mixing happens again, but that just causes the effect to soften.

In short, redrawing only covers up the pixels with total coverage.  The edge pixels are not completely part of the circle, so you cannot cover up the edge effects.

If you need to erase the circle, rather think about it in terms of restoring what was originally there.  You can probably copy the original content, then draw the circle, then when you want to move the circle, restore the original content and repeat the process.

[This previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041148/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-move-a-rectangular-pixel-region-inside-a-html5-canv) may give you some ideas about copying canvas regions.  It uses the drawImage method.  The best solution would combine the getImageData and putImageData methods.  I have [modified your Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/255t8/) to show you how you might do this.  You could try the following code:

```
var x, y, vx, vy;
var previousX = null, previousY = null;
var data = null;

function draw(){
    ctx.lineWidth = 2.5;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';

    drawCircle(x, y, 20);

    previousX = x;
    previousY = y;
}

function drawCircle(x, y, r){
  // Step 3: Replace the stuff that was underneath the previous circle
  if (data != null)
  {
    ctx.putImageData(data, previousX - r-5, previousY - r-5);
  }

  // Step 1: Copy the region in which we intend to draw a circle
  data = ctx.getImageData(x - r-5, y - r-5, 2 * r + 10, 2 * r + 10);

  // Step 2: Draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Your theoretical description was awesome, as well as your suggestion to work around it. The code example was a cherry on top of the icing.

Comment: @KevinA.Naudé Could you explain to beginners who are just starting out with canvas what you are doing? I can see in the fiddle that you solved the problem, but I can not imagine how. Are you drawing over the old circle?

Comment: @KevinSimper I have added comments marking three parts of code inside `drawCircle`.  Initially `data` is `null`, so step 3 is not executed the first time `drawCircle` is called. Step 1 saves the area under the circle. Step 2 draws the circle. Then time passes until the next frame, allowing you to see the drawn frame.  Finally, step 3 restores the canvas before you repeat the process.